# How to manipulate the WCF service result?

Tags: c#, wcf-binding, kendo-mobile

I have a kendo mobile application developed using VS AppBuilder extension. I have created a WCF service. I am using this service to bind the data with kendo charts. Here is my code of WCF service.

```
 public List<object> ProductCount(int week, int year)
    {
        List<object> lst = new List<object>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var weekNo = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                        DateTime.Now.Date,
                        currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                        currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products where Week_Number =" + week_No);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                lst.Add(dr["Quantity"].ToString());
            }
            int current = lst.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)); //result is 5000
            int goal = 10000;
            lst.Clear();
            dt.Clear();
            lst.Add("current:" + current);
            lst.Add("target:" + goal);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // new Error(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

This code returns result like this,
["current: 5000","target: 10000"]

But I want my result like this,
[{"current":5000, "target":10000}]

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to serialize the results into JSON?

Comment: Switch to a `Dictionary<string,int>` or possibly an [Ordered dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: After adding json serializer, it gives me the following result :"[\"current:5000\",\"target:10000\"]" But I want it like this , [{"current":5000, "target":10000}]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
lst.Add(new {
    current = current,
    target = goal
});
```

instead of:

```
lst.Add("current:" + current);
lst.Add("target:" + goal);
```

This would add an object to your array that has `current` and `target` properties.